# How to add custome header in OData V4?

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have one ODataV4 services, with that I want to pass my custom header parameter with each request.

how to pass custom parameter in a header.

Is there any functionaly for passing custom header parameter with Odata V4 services?

Comment: this should help: https://blogs.sap.com/2016/07/13/set-and-get-custom-http-header/

Comment: The blog describes only a solution for Odatamodel V2 , but not Odatamodel V4. In Odatamodel v4 there is no method setHeaders

Answer (score 0):

There is an api called changeHttpHeaders for updating http headers. Unfortunately it is available only from UI5 version 1.71.0.

Answer (score 0):

If your UI5 version is below 1.71.0, you can use the below method to setup your custom headers.

```
    setApplicationIDHeader: function (headerName, headerValue) {
    var o = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {
        var res = o.apply(this, arguments);
        //Replace below line and use your own logic to identify your request
        if (arguments[0] === "GET" && arguments[1].indexOf("companyContext") > -1) {
            this.setRequestHeader(headerName, headerValue);
        }
        return res;
    }
    }
```